# How to Make a Specific Animation Play Once a Certain Requirement is Met?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I know how to basically do this, but I'm making a sword with multiple attacks. I know how to do transitions and to lay it all out, but I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Here's the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwAnim : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool swing;
    public Animator anim;
    bool sprint;
    bool air;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        swing = false;
        sprint = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire3") && !swing)
        {
            sprint = true;
            anim.SetBool("Sprinting", true);
            anim.SetBool("Swinging", false);


        }

        if (!Input.GetButton("Fire3"))
        {
            sprint = false;
            anim.SetBool("Sprinting", false);
            //anim.SetBool("Swinging", false);

        }

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && !swing && !air)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Sprinting", false);
            Swing();
        }

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && air)
        {
           // anim.SetBool("Sprinting", false);
           //Swing();
        }

    }    

        void Swing()
        {
            // anim.Play();
            swing = true;
            StartCoroutine(Cool());
            StartCoroutine(CoolTwo());
            // StartCoroutine(Trail());
        }

       

        IEnumerator Cool()
        {
            anim.SetBool("Swinging", true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
            anim.SetBool("Swinging", false);
           
        }

        IEnumerator CoolTwo()
        {
            //canSwing = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            swing = false;

        }

        public void Grounded(bool isGr)
        {
            if (!isGr)
            {
                anim.SetBool("In Air", true);
                air = true;
                Debug.Log("jump");
            }

            if (isGr)
            {
                anim.SetBool("In Air", false);
                air = false;
                Debug.Log("nope");
            }
        }
    
}
```

The problem is when Fire1 is pressed and while in the air.
It won't allow the player to swing, which is good, but as soon as I put in another function, It doesn't work.

Here's what I've tried.

```
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && air )
        {
            anim.SetBool("Sprinting", false);
           AirSwing();

        }

    }    

        void Swing()
        {
            // anim.Play();
            swing = true;
            StartCoroutine(Cool());
            StartCoroutine(CoolTwo());
            // StartCoroutine(Trail());
        }

        void AirSwing()
        {
            StartCoroutine(CoolAir());

        }


    IEnumerator Cool()
        {
        anim.SetBool("Swinging", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        anim.SetBool("Swinging", false);

    } 

    IEnumerator CoolAir()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Swinging", true);
        anim.SetBool("In Air", true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        anim.SetBool("Swinging", false);
        anim.SetBool("In Air", false);


    }
```

If anyone could help, that would be great!
I'm still kinda new to Unity and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you've stepped on slicky path of programming and suddenly put yourself in a sequential-conditional-execution-booby-trap :D That's ok, bro, we've been there all. So, I'll try to explain shortly, hope you'll figure out the rest. First, your `Hero` has a state: walking, standing, grounded, flying, swinging etc. Two problems here: it is complex and basically non-existent outside of `Update()` context. So first we introdcue `state` and split it immediatly:

```
enum GroundState
{
    Grounded,
    JumpingUp,
    Levitating,
    FallingDown
}
enum AttackState
{
    Idle,
    Swinging,
    Blocking
}
```

Those staes would help yout to build gameplay logic and after that to control animations as well. You can build whatever logic you like, adding more states, block one by entring another, just give every behavior at least its own method (a class is better, but hey, you'll figure out why pretty soon), so you'll be at least feel better reading your own code :)